# Facebook Login doesn't doesn't dismiss Login Dialog after login

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, sfsafariviewcontroller

Using `LoginManager` from the Facebook iOS SDK to login like so:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { (loginResult) in
```

The Login Dialog opens facebook.com through Safari, which has a button for me to

> Log In with the Facebook App

When I click "Continue" in the Facebook app I am returned back to my app, however the Login Dialog is not dismissed even though `loginResult` returns `.success`.

This is what is displayed after returning to my app after being successfully logged in:
[image]

The only option is for me to click 'Cancel'. It seems like the Login Dialog is `SFAuthenticationViewController`, which currently contains 0 results on a Google search.

It seems problems other people have had in the past was that in their `AppDelegate` they were not calling the appropriate authorization flow processing in `application:openURL:options:` but that is successfully being called like so:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    print("application open url\n\(url)\noptions \(options)")

    if url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("fb") {
       print("Finishing Facebook log in flow")
       return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
    } else {
        print("Finishing Google sign in flow")
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
    }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is some incompatibility issues since I am using Swift 4 on iOS 11 Developer beta, and the fact that there are no results online for `SFAuthenticationViewController` which is seemingly being used.

I am unsure why the dialog isn't automatically being dismissed.

---

**Update:**

I created a brand new, blank app with only a single button and the `FacebookCore` and `FacebookLogin` dependencies and the issue still persists.

Steps followed:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started
3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login

Comment: Is this in simulator?

Comment: @murphguy no on a physical device.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `SDKApplicationDelegate`? instantiate it on a `let` variable, and parse the result accordingly, either by printing something for a false result, or sending a Notification to your controller to display an alert etc. Im suggesting this because i have the same set up, but with a value check before the return, which works. I have not tried it on iOS 11 yet however.

Comment: also, according to their SDK module, they have a login method for read permission, and seperate one for publish permissions, perhaps you're using the wrong one here? Also check your urlSchemes.

Comment: @murphguy `SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)` returns `true`. In `Info.plist` I have set up `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` which contains fbapi, fb-messenger-api, fbauth2, fbshareextension.

Comment: I believe this might be tied-in with Apple's decision to remove Social-Media Login support across apps. While a result like this seems unlikely, it is possible that Safari has a protocol to detect that you left the app to login. What i've heard is that you have to stay within safari to login with facebook now. I read an article on this a while back, i'll add it here when i find it

Comment: They've also announced an App Password Service tied in with keychain, which should allow you to set a password for your user based on a login type, it's only been informally announced by engineers working on Keychain, so this feature (if it does become public), will probably only be release in a later version.

Comment: @murphguy Doh! I don't know why, but I only just tried using a simulator now using and it's working perfectly. I think it must be a change to iOS 11 that Facebook will have to implement or provide documentation on how to handle changes in iOS 11. I don't think there's anything we can do. I appreciate the help dude.

Comment: @murphguy Hang on, scrap that. My simulator is running iOS 11.0...

Comment: The same beta version?

Comment: @murphguy no, my physical device has beta 4. I am going to install beta 5 now and see if anything changes, though I doubt it.

Comment: @murphguy another difference is my physical device has the Facebook app installed, and my simulator doesn't. So that's probably the main reason.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a good point.. however, have you tested out what happens when login in through safari? ie, not pressing the option to redirect to the FB app when in Facebook's auth screen in the safari controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151445/discussion-between-gbhall-and-murphguy).

Comment: This hasn't been fixed yet, any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Now working in SDK `0.3.0`: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/releases

---

Update, official response from Facebook:

> Hi Gareth,
>
> Thanks for flagging this! iOS 11 is still in beta, and we don't
>   currently support it.
>
> Best regards, Günay

---

This is a bug on devices running iOS 11. Works fine on devices running iOS 10.

Bug report filed here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/172

Comment: This hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: SDK 0.3.0? there is no 0.3.0.  are you using FBSDKLoginKit?

Comment: @PabloMartinez I am using Swift. Here are the latest releases: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/releases

Comment: @gbhall I am facing same issue with iOS 13 now, will you please advice something on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue also with **Swift 3** on iOS 11

Comment: Hopefully Facebook updates their SDK before iOS 11 is released to the public.

Comment: Pretty confident about that.

Comment: For now I used a workaround, as if I call self.dismiss I can dismiss it I call it twice for iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot the following function in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }
```